# Why does this code result in a dataframe longer than 2000 columns?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to filter out 2000 columns with the highest MAD values from a pandas dataframe but when I run this code, it results in a dataframe larger than 2000 columns (3556 to be exact). I confirmed that it wasn't a rounding error by changing 2000 to 1999. Why does this code result in a dataframe longer than 2000 columns?

```
print(split_df.shape)
mad_values = split_df.mad()
top_columns = mad_values.nlargest(2000).index
split_df = split_df[top_columns]
print(split_df.shape)
```

Here is the output:

(580, 60660)

(580, 3556)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, [`mad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mad.html) was *deprecated* in [1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#other-deprecations) by [`pandas/pull/46707`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/46707) and removed in [2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes). So I assume you're using an older version of that one (*e.g* `1.4.4`). Now, to answer your question, the only explanation I see is that *"the original dataframe has duplicated headers"*.

Here is a minimal reproducible example :

```
# pd.__version__ # 1.4.4

split_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(-1, 5), columns=[*"AABCA"])

    A   A   B   C   A
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
5  25  26  27  28  29
```

```
split_df.columns.is_unique # False
```

Now, after using your code, see how we end up with `7` cols (`>3`) :

```
# this is your code

print(split_df.shape) # (6, 5)

mad_values = split_df.mad()
top_columns = mad_values.nlargest(3).index
split_df = split_df[top_columns]

print(split_df.shape) # (6, 7)
```

Intermediate mad :

```
A    7.5  # << 1
A    7.5  # << 2
B    7.5
C    7.5
A    7.5  # << 3
dtype: float64
```